# Shape square effect

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I started do a simple shape or square just using CSS3 but I got stuck, Do you know how can I make the effect below?

Pic:

[image: desired effect]

My CSS:

```
.square{
    width: 150px; 
    height: 100px; 
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg); 
    -moz-transform: skew(20deg); 
    -o-transform: skew(20deg); 
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort of create that with triangular borders.

```
#box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    border-left: 400px solid #e3dd2d;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
}
#box:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;   
    border-top: 70px solid #e3dd2d;
    position: absolute;
    left: -220px;
    bottom:-80px;   
}
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/f5w8omLL/)**

**UPDATE**

```css
#box {
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        border-left: 400px solid #e3dd2d;
        border-top: 30px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
        position: relative;
    }
    #box:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute; 
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 25px solid transparent;
        border-right: 25px solid transparent;   
        border-top: 70px solid #e3dd2d;
        position: absolute;
        left: -220px;
        bottom:-80px;   
    }
    #box div {
        display: table;
        margin-left: -400px;
        text-align: center;  
    }
    #box div span{  
        display: table-cell;
        width: 400px;  
        height: 150px;
        vertical-align: middle;  
    }
```

```html
<div id="box">
    <div>    
        <span>
            Some text inside           
        </span>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**[UPDATED EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f5w8omLL/1/)**

Comment: thanks very much is that what i looking for, but look how can i have a text inside? i tried put a text but text goes out :(

Comment: @user964836 The triangle itself is actualy the border of the DIV. If you want text inside the triangle, you'll have to put some text in another element and give that element a total negative margin the same as the width of your triangle is. 
I'll update the jsfiddle in a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You should be able to use a combination of `perspective`, `perspective-origin`, and `transform: rotateY()`

For example:

```css
/* Need a wrapper to use perspective */
#div1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-perspective: 150px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    perspective: 150px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}

/* Apply rotateY() to child */
#div2 {
    padding: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(25deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotateY(25deg);
}

/* CSS triangle trick */
#div2::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -19px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">HELLO</div>
</div>
```